# How to hide a Table Header using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

How to hide table headers in javascript.

In detail am using easyui-datagrid in which i have to hide the column header.

Please guide me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It always helps to include some sample code in order to be able to provide you with a good answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you use pure javascript without the help of any framework, like jQuery etc, you should give an id to your table and assign the table object to a variable:

```
var tb = document.getElementById("your-table-id");
```

and then find the "thead" tag inside the table and hide it, as follows:

```
tb.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0].style.display = "none";
```

note that getElementsByTagName returns an array of html elements,
since a valid table can have 0 or 1 "thead" occurrencies, if you are sure that your table has headers you can securely access the first element and change it's visibility.

Comment: Hi Thanks this is fixed. There is data-option in easyui-datagrid as data-options="showHeader:false"

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use JavaScript, then you should be able to use standard selectors and jQuery and use the Hide method:

```
$("#id or .class of header row").hide();
```

But I'd recommend using CSS instead:

```
#id or .class of header row {
    display: none;
}
```

It's lower impact using the CSS route, and all the jQuery will do it apply the same style directly to the element.

Comment: dear Kieron display:none hide my table header.but can i show it on table:hover?please

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this code:

```
 $('#my-ddata-grid').datagrid({
 ....
 ....
 });

jQuery('.datagrid-header-inner').hide();
```

You can also remove other elements, like the pagination-bar like this:

```
jQuery('.datagrid-pager.pagination').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked me :

```
<style>
.datagrid-header-row {
    visibility: collapse;
}
</style>
```